# Pig "Max" command for pig-0.12.1 and pig-0.13.0 with Hadoop-2.4.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script I got from Hortonworks that works fine with pig-0.9.2.15 with Hadoop-1.0.3.16. But when I run it with pig-0.12.1(recompiled with -Dhadoopversion=23) or pig-0.13.0 on Hadoop-2.4.0, it won't work.

It seems the following line is where the problem is.

```
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;
```

Here's the whole script.

```
batting = load 'pig_data/Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',');
runs = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID, $1 as year, $8 as runs;
grp_data = GROUP runs by (year);
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;
join_max_run = JOIN max_runs by ($0, max_runs), runs by (year,runs);
join_data = FOREACH join_max_run GENERATE $0 as year, $2 as playerID, $1 as runs;
STORE join_data INTO './join_data';
```

And here's the hadoop error info:

> 2014-07-29 18:03:02,957 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:
>   Exception while executing (Name: grp_data: Local
>   Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-34 Operator Key: scope-34):
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2106:
>   Error executing an algebraic function 2014-07-29 18:03:02,958 [main]
>   ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map
>   reduce job(s) failed!

How can I fix this if I still want to use "MAX" function? Thank you!

Here's the complete information:

> 14/07/29 17:50:11 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL
>   14/07/29 17:50:11 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType :
>   MAPREDUCE 14/07/29 17:50:11 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked
>   MAPREDUCE as the ExecType 2014-07-29 17:50:12,104 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.13.0 (r1606446) compiled
>   Jun 29 2014, 02:27:58 2014-07-29 17:50:12,104 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to:
>   /root/hadooptestingsuite/scripts/tests/pig_test/hadoop2/pig_1406677812103.log
>   2014-07-29 17:50:13,050 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils -
>   Default bootup file /root/.pigbootup not found 2014-07-29 17:50:13,415
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.jobtracker.address 2014-07-29 17:50:13,415 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29 17:50:13,415 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine -
>   Connecting to hadoop file system at:
>   hdfs://namenode.cmda.hadoop.com:8020 2014-07-29 17:50:14,302 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine -
>   Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: namenode.cmda.hadoop.com:8021
>   2014-07-29 17:50:14,990 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29 17:50:15,570 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29
>   17:50:15,665 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.newplan.BaseOperatorPlan -
>   Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE 1 time(s). 2014-07-29
>   17:50:15,705 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.textoutputformat.separator is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator 2014-07-29 17:50:15,791
>   [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features
>   used in the script: HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY 2014-07-29 17:50:15,873 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer -
>   {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune,
>   GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter,
>   MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer,
>   PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter,
>   StreamTypeCastInserter],
>   RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]} 2014-07-29
>   17:50:16,319 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler
>   - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false 2014-07-29 17:50:16,377 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.CombinerOptimizer
>   - Choosing to move algebraic foreach to combiner 2014-07-29 17:50:16,410 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler$LastInputStreamingOptimizer
>   - Rewrite: POPackage->POForEach to POPackage(JoinPackager) 2014-07-29 17:50:16,417 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size before optimization: 3 2014-07-29 17:50:16,418 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - Merged 1 map-reduce splittees. 2014-07-29 17:50:16,418 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - Merged 1 out of total 3 MR operators. 2014-07-29 17:50:16,418 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size after optimization: 2 2014-07-29 17:50:16,493 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29
>   17:50:16,575 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy -
>   Connecting to ResourceManager at
>   namenode.cmda.hadoop.com/10.0.3.1:8050 2014-07-29 17:50:16,973 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig
>   script settings are added to the job 2014-07-29 17:50:17,007 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent 2014-07-29 17:50:17,007
>   [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3 2014-07-29 17:50:17,007 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress 2014-07-29 17:50:17,020
>   [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Reduce phase detected, estimating # of required reducers. 2014-07-29 17:50:17,020 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Using reducer estimator: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
>   2014-07-29 17:50:17,064 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.InputSizeReducerEstimator
>   - BytesPerReducer=1000000000 maxReducers=999 totalInputFileSize=6398990 2014-07-29 17:50:17,067 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting Parallelism to 1 2014-07-29 17:50:17,067 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.tasks
>   is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces 2014-07-29
>   17:50:17,068 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - This job cannot be converted run in-process 2014-07-29 17:50:17,068 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - creating jar file Job2337803902169382273.jar 2014-07-29 17:50:20,957 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - jar file Job2337803902169382273.jar created 2014-07-29 17:50:20,957 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar 2014-07-29
>   17:50:21,001 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting up multi store job 2014-07-29 17:50:21,036 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is
>   false, will not generate code. 2014-07-29 17:50:21,036 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move
>   generated code to distributed cacche 2014-07-29 17:50:21,046 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Setting key
>   [pig.schematuple.classes] with classes to deserialize [] 2014-07-29
>   17:50:21,310 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission. 2014-07-29 17:50:21,311 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation -
>   mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use
>   mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address 2014-07-29 17:50:21,332 [JobControl]
>   INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to
>   ResourceManager at namenode.cmda.hadoop.com/10.0.3.1:8050 2014-07-29
>   17:50:21,366 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29 17:50:22,606
>   [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input
>   paths to process : 1 2014-07-29 17:50:22,606 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total
>   input paths to process : 1 2014-07-29 17:50:22,629 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total
>   input paths (combined) to process : 1 2014-07-29 17:50:22,729
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number
>   of splits:1 2014-07-29 17:50:22,745 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2014-07-29 17:50:23,026
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter -
>   Submitting tokens for job: job_1406677482986_0003 2014-07-29
>   17:50:23,258 [JobControl] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl - Submitted
>   application application_1406677482986_0003 2014-07-29 17:50:23,340
>   [JobControl] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track
>   the job:
>   http://namenode.cmda.hadoop.com:8088/proxy/application_1406677482986_0003/
>   2014-07-29 17:50:23,340 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - HadoopJobId: job_1406677482986_0003 2014-07-29 17:50:23,340 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Processing aliases batting,grp_data,max_runs,runs 2014-07-29 17:50:23,340 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - detailed locations: M: batting[3,10],runs[5,7],max_runs[7,11],grp_data[6,11] C:
>   max_runs[7,11],grp_data[6,11] R: max_runs[7,11] 2014-07-29
>   17:50:23,340 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - More information at: http://namenode.cmda.hadoop.com:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1406677482986_0003
>   2014-07-29 17:50:23,357 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 0% complete 2014-07-29 17:50:23,357 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Running jobs are [job_1406677482986_0003] 2014-07-29 17:51:15,564 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 50% complete 2014-07-29 17:51:15,564 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Running jobs are [job_1406677482986_0003] 2014-07-29 17:51:18,582 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure. 2014-07-29 17:51:18,582 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_1406677482986_0003 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2014-07-29 17:51:18,582 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2014-07-29 17:51:18,825 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0:
>   Exception while executing (Name: grp_data: Local
>   Rearrange[tuple]{bytearray}(false) - scope-73 Operator Key: scope-73):
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2106:
>   Error executing an algebraic function 2014-07-29 17:51:18,825 [main]
>   ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map
>   reduce job(s) failed! 2014-07-29 17:51:18,826 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script
>   Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
>   2.4.0 0.13.0  root    2014-07-29 17:50:16 2014-07-29 17:51:18 HASH_JOIN,GROUP_BY
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId    Alias   Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1406677482986_0003    batting,grp_data,max_runs,runs  MULTI_QUERY,COMBINER    Message:
>   Job failed!
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from
>   "hdfs://namenode.cmda.hadoop.com:8020/user/root/pig_data/Batting.csv"
>
> Output(s):
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1406677482986_0003   ->  null, null
>
> 2014-07-29 17:51:18,826 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Failed! 2014-07-29 17:51:18,827 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2106: Error executing
>   an algebraic function Details at logfile:
>   /root/hadooptestingsuite/scripts/tests/pig_test/hadoop2/pig_1406677812103.log
>   2014-07-29 17:51:18,828 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job scope-58
>   failed, hadoop does not return any error message Details at logfile:
>   /root/hadooptestingsuite/scripts/tests/pig_test/hadoop2/pig_1406677812103.log

Comment: can you post the job logs or any more information from jt logs about this particular error? Did it launch a job at all?

Comment: Certianly. Here's the one for pig-0.13.0. I can also post for pig-0.12.0. I have tested other pig scripts before running this one. Other scripts passed.

Comment: Since your job job_1406677482986_0003 has failed, it must have useful information to debug the root cause. If you can check the logs of this job (log of failed map task), please paste the any stack trace in those logs.

Comment: Thank you, I'll pull the log. I've also tried local mode, still, it works with another pig script but not this one

Answer (score 1):

try by casting MAX function

max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, (int)MAX(runs.runs) as max_runs;

hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

You should use data types in your load statement.

```
runs = FOREACH batting GENERATE $0 as playerID:chararray, $1 as year:int, $8 as runs:int;
```

If this doesn't help for some reason, try explicit casting.

```
max_runs = FOREACH grp_data GENERATE group as grp, MAX((int)runs.runs) as max_runs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank both @BigData and @Mikko Kupsu for the hint. The issue does indeed have something to do the datatype casting.

After specifying the data type of each column as follows everything runs great.

```
batting = 
    LOAD '/user/root/pig_data/Batting.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
    AS (playerID: CHARARRAY, yearID: INT, stint: INT, teamID: CHARARRAY, lgID: CHARARRAY,
    G: INT, G_batting: INT, AB: INT, R: INT, H: INT, two_B: INT, three_B: INT, HR: INT, RBI: INT, 
    SB: INT, CS: INT, BB:INT, SO: INT, IBB: INT, HBP: INT, SH: INT, SF: INT, GIDP: INT, G_old: INT);
```